# Custom Result from Spring JPA Query

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a User class and I want to pull all the objects of that class from the database. I am using Spring Data JPA and fetching data using `@Query`. Is there a way I can hide partial digits of phone number of user. Something like converting 123-456-7890 to 123-XXX-XXXX.

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT u FROM User u ORDER BY u.name")
 List<User> getAllUsers();
```

I am using user object at multiple locationsin the code, so fetching and updating records everytime will be very time consuming and users will grow over the time so it will also affect the performance.

Is there any way(some post processors or anything) which can handle it while populating data into object after fething from database.

Any pointers will be very helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: You might be interested in using converters: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-attribute-converters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your data when fetching using Attribute converter.

```
public class PhoneNumberAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<String, String> {
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(String value) {
        return value;
    }
    @Override
    public String convertToEntityAttribute(String a) {
        String value = a.substring(0, 3) + s.substring(3).replaceAll("[0-9]", "X");
        return value;
    }
}
```

And use it on field

```
@Convert(converter = PhoneNumberAttributeConverter.class)
private String phoneNumber;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I applied this change and now everywhere its like 123-XXX-XXXX. Is there a way to display the complete phone number for admin users.

Comment: Are you using entity  class for response or use dto class? You can use a serializer then and use when you want to hide.

Comment: Sending entity class back using responseEntity. Can you share any url with example, it will help me understand better.

Comment: @FoxHowl Are you want an automatic handle on user role right? Using entity class as the response is not a good pattern. If you use a separate response dto then you can use [custom serializer](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization#on-mapper)

Comment: Did you get you answer for this question ?

Comment: thanks for your input about serializer. I am half way thru the solution. I have to also same thing while downlaoding data.Serializer is working fine with JsonView for UI but not for downloads.